# Using Maven, Log4j config error when deploying. (IntelliJ IDEA on Mac)

Tags: xml, maven, intellij-idea, jboss, log4j

When I use Maven in IntelliJ IDEA, I first run clean, then install, then when I run the server I receive errors. I am new to setting this up and not sure how to properly config everything. Below are my logs. It displays connected to server then warnings appear then the errors after the list of controllers is being shown.

```
11:02:54,377 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started in 3761ms - Started 185 of 257 services (58 services are passive or on-demand)
Connected to server
[2016-12-08 11:02:54,670] Artifact ozs-ear:ear exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...


11:03:00,279 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@57f81bc2: defining beans [controllers]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@471d0906
11:03:00,498 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
11:03:00,499 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/ex/exlog.log (No such file or directory)
11:03:00,499 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
11:03:00,499 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
11:03:00,499 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
11:03:00,500 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
11:03:00,500 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
11:03:00,500 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
11:03:00,500 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
11:03:00,501 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
11:03:00,501 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
11:03:00,501 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:809)
11:03:00,501 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22)   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to write the logs to `/logs/ex/exlog.log`. Does the directory exist and does your server have permissions to write to it? Try creating the `/logs/ex` directory manually and changing its owner and permissions so the server can write the log file.